# How to classify similar looking dataset but belonging to different class

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes, anomaly-detection

I've got a user dataset in which there are two classes. The size of dataset if 50,000. Class_A=5000 , class_B= 45000.
Now the problem is that there are some instances(500) which though belong to class_A, but looks very very similar to class_B. I cant just discard these 500 datapoints as they belong to class_A and I already have few examples in class_A.

How can I resolve this problem ? Is there any name for such kind of problem or scenario as I couldn't find anything in this regard.

Comment: What do you need to do with your data? Perform supervised learning or something else?

Comment: Supervised learning. Its crucial for me to predict Class_A with higher accuracy, hence Im concerned about the similarity in those 500 datapoints which are very similar to data points from class_B (i.e. bit difficult to distinguish)

Comment: Mis-classification error / rate? You have an imbalanced data set, which will require some effort to deal with. So these 500 cases which belong to A you believe should actually be in B? And you want a method to solve this, that is try to classify these 500 in B?

Comment: @user2974951 No actually I want the separation to be clear. I guess I need to create more features or engineer some new. What say ?

Comment: What do you mean "separation to be clear"? These data points may just be odd and cannot be nicely sorted into one class or the other. You could use a different metric or algorithm (for ex. SVM) which could separate these with a transformation of your space.

Comment: You may consider the 500 cases as being from a third class, say class_C. It should be easier for a classification model to draw the contour of class_C alone, instead of class_A + class_C. Now, if your data does not reflect any difference between classes B and C, you will probably have a poor classification performance.